# Implement Python class based on the parameter passed to constructor

Tags: python, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class, derived

I am implementing a python class, which constructs another object in the constructor whose type is determined based on the parameter passed to it.  For example in the code below `"workerA"` has the behavior of class `"MyAClass"` and `"workerB"` object has the behavior of `"MyBClass"`.

I am using this method instead of deriving different class from the base class because the BaseClass is already being used in a different code which cannot be changed. So if I want another behavior of BaseClass as for `"MyBClass"` behavior then I only need to passed the parameter `dbtype = "MyBClass"` to it.

Is there any better method which can be used and which gives the same result?

```
  import sys

  # MyAClass definition
  class MyAClass :

     def __init__(self, serverSettings):
        self._serverSettings = serverSettings

     def initialize(self):
        self._init = 1;
        print("Calling", sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name)

     def add(self):
        self._init = 2;
        print("Calling", sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name)

     def finalize(self):
        self._init = 3;
        print("Calling", sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name)

     def __del__(self):
        print('Calling destructor of class ', self.__class__.__name__)


  # MyBClass definition
  class MyBClass :

     def __init__(self, serverSettings):
        self._serverSettings = serverSettings

     def initialize(self):
        self._init = 1;
        print("Calling", sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name)

     def add(self):
        self._init = 2;
        print("Calling", sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name)

     def finalize(self):
        self._init = 3;
        print("Calling", sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name)

     def __del__(self):
        print('Calling destructor of class ', self.__class__.__name__)


  # The base class which will be called in main program
  class BaseClass :

     def __init__(self, serverSettings, dbtype = None):

        if(dbtype == None):
           self.__worker = MyAClass(serverSettings)
        elif(dbtype == "MyBClass") :
           self.__worker = MyBClass(serverSettings)
        else :
           print("Undefined type")

     def initialize(self):
        self.__worker.initialize()

     def add(self):
        self.__worker.add()

     def finalize(self):
        self.__worker.finalize()


  if __name__ == "__main__":

     serverSettings = dict()

     serverSettings["address"] = "localhost"
     serverSettings["name"] = "Testname"

     workerA = BaseClass(serverSettings)
     workerA.add()

     workerB = BaseClass(serverSettings, dbtype = "MyBClass")
     workerB.finalize()
```

Comment: Instead of using the `dbtype` argument, you could just use the right class.

Comment: @Kluas D, I tried the method of passing the class, and it worked.  To me it seemed a better method as what I have implemented.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't produce the same output as your original program, but would something like this work for your purposes? Unless you're querying the method name (as you are above), you should get functionally identical results.

```
class BaseClass :
    def __init__(self, serverSettings, dbtype=None):

        if(dbtype == None):
           self.__worker = MyAClass(serverSettings)
        elif(dbtype == "MyBClass") :
           self.__worker = MyBClass(serverSettings)
        else :
           print("Undefined type")

    def __getattribute__(self, x):
        settings = object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__').get('_BaseClass__worker')
        return settings.__getattribute__(x)
```

Alternately, using some class twizzing like this:

```
class BaseClass :
    def __init__(self, serverSettings, dbtype='MyAClass'):
        dbtypes = {'MyAClass': MyAClass,
                    'MyBClass': MyBClass}
        if dbtype not in dbtypes:
           raise("Undefined type")
        self.__class__ = dbtypes[dbtype]
        self.__init__(serverSettings)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following code changes based on the suggestions

```
  class BaseClass :

     def __init__(self, serverSettings, Classtype = MyAClass):

        authclasses = [MyAClass, MyBClass]
        if Classtype not in authclasses :
           self.__worker = MyAClass(serverSettings)
        else :
           self.__worker = MyBClass(serverSettings)

     def __getattribute__(self, x):
        settings = object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__').get('_BaseClass__worker')
        return settings.__getattribute__(x)
```